# Bootstrap 3 navbar header isn't tappable/resonding on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented a Bootstrap 3 Nav and I'm encountering this issue for the first time in many years of using Bootstrap.

On desktop browser with device emulation the nav collapses and works as expected, however, when tapping on the header on an *actual* mobile device it just won't budge. Connecting an iPhone via USB and debugging on Safari shows that on tapping the header no change is made, i.e. the classes `collapse in` are not added and no HTML is changed.

What I've tried/checked:

- Adding in `maximum-scale=1.0` in the meta viewport
- Checked that my `data-toggle` and `data-target` are correct, which they are (and again, works on desktop)
- Replacing my bootstrap.min.js from the Bootstrap CDN
- Stripping back CSS

[View my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20667/)

Answer (score 4):

Seems Bootstrap requires the toggle to utilise `<a href="#">` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue within the last month. Try changing the z-index value of the drop down list items. The content may be rendering, but hidden behind another element (header image or something of that nature). You should change that element's z-index value as well.

I would also recommend not setting height values for you navigation. By default, bootstrap wants the drop down menu to 'move' the content below. It cannot do this if the height is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up re height values. I did try using a higher z-index to no avail. The only thing that did work was adding a `href` to the nav element.